# When do I need to use esc_attr when using WordPress internal functions

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, escaping

When I am putting a WordPress value inside the attribute tag, for example, the following method does not need `esc_attr`

e.g.

```
// JS code
alert('<?php echo get_bloginfo('name');?>');
```

the following method does need `esc_attr`

```
// JS code
alert('<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_title);?>');
```

What is the convention used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can look at the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr).

> Encodes < > & " ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote,
>   single quote). Will never double encode entities.

Given that, arguably, [both of those strings need sanitization](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation). Imagine a site name like `>> "My" Website's Great Title <<"`

Also, since you are using this in Javascript, you should probably be using [`esc_js`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_js) instead.

The convention is, "understand how markup works, and how malicious hackers work, and act accordingly." That is how you know how to use these functions. Also, **Trust No One**.

See also this article from our member [Stephen Harris](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris): [Data Sanitization and Validation With WordPress](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress/)

Comment: Actually my finding is `get_bloginfo('name');` does not need to be escaped, when I set my blog name as `"My" Website's Great Title <<"`, and print it out via `echo  get_bloginfo('name') `, it is already escaped, i.e. `My&quot; Website&#039;s Great Title &lt;&lt;`.

Comment: You can reference this: http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentyeleven/1.5/header.php, the default theme also print the blogname directly, e.g. `bloginfo( 'name' );`

Comment: I wouldn't depend on the theme for this.

Answer (score 1):

You use `esc_attr()` when you are outputting something intended to be in an HTML attribute.

In your case, you should be using `esc_js()`, or possibly `json_encode()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your post title has single quote in it. Output of your code would be

alert('It's bad');

that is, breaking your JavaScript code and you will get "Unexpected identifier". When you use [esc_attr](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr), output would be

alert('It&#039;s bad');

Post title will be encoded so it works within the strings.