# Replace the attribute_escape to esc_attr()

Tags: posts

I opened a similar topic, but since it is a little confusing, I decided to create a new topic to clarify more.
i run the website and i found the errors seems like: 
    `Notice: attribute_escape is deprecated since version 2.8! Use esc_attr() instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2638`
I search and i found some useful information like : [When do I need to use esc_attr when using WordPress internal functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75590/when-do-i-need-to-use-esc-attr-when-using-wordpress-internal-functions/75601#75601) , but sorry i am not undearstand..
The errors are in the post title. for example, this is my code of the `index.php`. Where exactly are the errors?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>          
    <div id="main" class="container_12">    
        <div id="content" class="grid_9 alpha">                 
            <?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=6' );?>      
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>     
                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID();?>">          
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> 
                    <?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>         
                    <?php if(is_sticky()):?> <article id="sticky_post"><div class="sticky-title"><h2>Welocome</h2></div></article> 
                    <?php endif;?>                                                                          
                    <?php if( in_array( $post->ID, array(354) ) )                   
                    {echo get_the_content();}                       
                    else 
                    {echo get_excerpt();}?>
                    <div id="more" class="container_12">                    
                    <p class="read-more"></p>  </div>                                                       
                <div class="dots"> <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dots.png" border="0" /></div>                             
                </div> <!-- end class post -->                      
            <?php endwhile; ?>                      
            <?php else : ?>     
            <h2> Not found </h2>        
            <p> Sorry but you are looking for something that isn't here. </p>       
        </div><!--content-->                    
    <?php endif; ?>                             
    </div><!--header_container-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What **Theme** are you using? Do you get the deprecated notice if you **switch to Twenty Twelve**? Do you get the deprecated notice if you **disable all Plugins**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deprecation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) is...

> status applied to features, characteristics, or practices to indicate that they should be avoided, typically because they have been superseded.

In other words, `attribute_escape` has been replaced by [`esc_attr`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr).

Any time you use a deprecated function WordPress triggers the error you're seeing.  Somewhere in your codebase a deprecated function is being used.

To fix the error, you need to locate where `attribute_escape` is in your code. It won't be in the WordPress core as deprecated function calls are removed.

So, search your entire `wp-content` directory for `attribute_escape`. When you find it, replace it with `esc_attr`. I would use the command like [`ack-grep`](http://betterthangrep.com/) for this.

```
$ cd /path/to/your/wordpress/install/wp-content
$ ack-grep attribute_escape
```

But any filesystem search will probably work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help! @Chip Bennett this theme is mine, i build itfrom scratch. I use only two plugins, when i switch to Twenty Twelve Theme, i don't have any message/error. I'll check the solution that you suggest to me.

Answer (score 0):

ohh. @chrisguitarguy i can't install the ack-grep,  I had to look in manual mode. The problem was in `functions.php` particular:

```
<?php

function the_title_trim($title) {
        $title = attribute_escape($title);
        $findthese = array(
                '#Protected:#',
                '#Private:#'
        );
        $replacewith = array(
                '', // What to replace "Protected:" with
                '' // What to replace "Private:" with
        );
        $title = preg_replace($findthese, $replacewith, $title);
        return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'the_title_trim');

?>
```

and replaced with :

```
<?php

function the_title_trim($title) {
        $title = esc_attr($title);
        $findthese = array(
                '#Protected:#',
                '#Private:#'
        );
        $replacewith = array(
                '', // What to replace "Protected:" with
                '' // What to replace "Private:" with
        );
        $title = preg_replace($findthese, $replacewith, $title);
        return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'the_title_trim');

?>
```

And finally works!